# Issue removing a NULL value from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, null

I've tried the following to remove the null values from a resultset.

```
if((is_null($value)) || ('NULL' === $value) || (null === $value))
```

none seem to be working.

Here's my full code:

```
// remove null values from contact details
$contactData[$key] = removeEmptyDataFromArray($contact);    
print "<pre>".print_r($contactData[$key],true)."</pre">;

// remove empty data function
function removeEmptyDataFromArray(array $filledData)
{
    foreach ($filledData as $key => $value )
    {
        if ((is_null($value)) || (strlen ( $value ) === 0) || ('NULL' == $value) || (NULL === $value))
        {
            unset ( $filledData [$key] );
        }
    }
    return $filledData;
}
```

And here are the results from my print_r:

```
firstname :
lastname :
middlename :
primary_emailaddress : someemail@email.com
```

Comment: var_dump $value to see what exactly it is.

Comment: my vardump is returning NULL

Comment: Yes, do a [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)/[`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to see what exactly is the data you are getting from your query. Then look into [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), [`is_null`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) to see what serves your purpose.

Comment: Can you show some more code that you are using?

Comment: Also, `'NULL' === $value` is not the way to check for NULL. Also, make sure you are checking against the correct value, like do you need to use an array index for the particular value, rather than the _complete_ response from query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, instead of

```
if ((is_null($value)) || (strlen ( $value ) === 0) || ('NULL' == $value) || (NULL === $value))
```

try

```
if (empty($value))
```

Comment: Yes, and this is no trick :) just clarity of basic concepts of PHP and clarity of requirements. At the risk of offending you, I suggest a read of [programming by accident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation) :)

Comment: No offense taken. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

why not remove Null values from your query without php ?

```
 WHERE your_column is not null
```

or

```
WHERE your_column <> ''
```

depends on how is your column. you have used the whole function just to remove the null values while in sql is just 5 words

Comment: Yes, why did it not strike me? :)

Comment: i cannot exclude rows where one of the columns is null. I need to make sure that i still get the results despite the null value